# How to change the camera's frame rate on the fly using camerax API Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera2, android-camerax

We are working on an image processing application which takes in live frames from the camera (using cameraX) and analyzes them using C++. The customer will be using this app for 8 hours, during which only a few events that require image processing will occur. The rest of the time we'd like to have a standby mode with lower frame rate to save power. When the standby mode detects an event, it will trigger the high frame rate mode. I was able to change the frame rate at startup using the following code:

```java
ext.setCaptureRequestOption(
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,
    Range<Int>(4, 6)
)
```

This works great and achieves the power saving goal we are looking for. But I need to be able to switch frame rates instantaneously which I can't figure out how to do.

I tried calling the following command while the camera is already running:

```java
ext.setCaptureRequestOption(
    CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,
        Range<Int>(30, 30)
)
```

This doesn't change the frame rate and gives the following error (the app doesn't crash):

> Exception while executing runnable
> androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1@7768e81
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Option values conflicts:
> camera2.captureRequest.option.android.control.aeTargetFpsRange,
> existing value (ALWAYS_OVERRIDE)=[4, 6], conflicting
> (ALWAYS_OVERRIDE)=[30, 30] at
> androidx.camera.core.impl.MutableOptionsBundle.insertOption(MutableOptionsBundle.java:110
> at
> androidx.camera.core.impl.CaptureConfig$Builder.addImplementationOptions(CaptureConfig.java:337)

When I call this at startup it sets a high frame rate so I know it's not an issue with choosing a compatible frame rate for our device (I should mention that we are using a Galaxy S10e, and that is the only device that this app will ever be deployed on). I am also able to get it to work by unbinding and re-binding the camera after calling the above capture request:

```
// Unbind use cases before rebinding
unbindCamera()
// Bind use cases to camera
camera = cameraProvider?.bindToLifecycle(activity, cameraSelector)
```

But this causes a ~1.4 second delay before the high frame rate analysis starts, which is unacceptable for us as the events may be very short.

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the frame rate while the analysis is still running? Any help would be much appreciated.

If this is possible in camera2 and not cameraX then that's OK.